# Find the extension of a webpage

Tags: .htaccess

Some website including my own use .htaccess files to make their urls look nice.

Is there a way to find out what the "ugly url" looks like ?

Comment: Yes. Look at the rewriting logic in the `.htaccess` file.

Comment: @RB You can't see other people's .htaccess files (unless they've done something terribly wrong).

Comment: From where? As a user of another web page? From within the server logic of the own web page? From a script within the browser? ... ??

Comment: And why should there be any “ugly url” (accessible or otherwise) in the first place? (Also, your title talks about the “extension” – there are some strange OS where the file name extension must match the type of a file, but in reality, the two are completely unrelated concepts.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, its not possible without guessing the URL.